# Slow CRTP pattern in MSVC 14

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, crtp

I'm working with CRTP pattern and noticed that MSVC 14 (Visual Studio 2015 Update 1) can't optimize away (even with -O2) the overhead of the following CRTP pattern.

```
template <typename T, size_t N, typename Derived>
struct Base
{
    __forceinline Derived& operator+=(const Derived &b)
    {
        return (static_cast<Derived&>(*this) = static_cast<Derived&>(*this) + b);
    }
};

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct A: Base<T,N, A<T,N>>
{
    T data[N];
};

template <typename T, size_t N>
__forceinline A<T, N> operator+(const A<T, N> &a, const A<T, N> &b)
{
    A<T, N> result;

    // just an unroll helper, because MSVC doesn't unroll small loops
    unroll_for<0, N>([](size_t i)
    {
        result.data[i] = a.data[i] + b.data[i];
    });

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    A <float,4> a;
    A <float,4> b;

    a += b;

    return 0;
};
```

GCC and Clang do great job and the generated code is as fast as a manually generated variant without any indirection. However the running time of the MSVC generated code is dramatically slower. If I remove the `(static_cast<Derived&>(*this) = static_cast<Derived&>(*this) + b);` part and manually inline the body of `operator+` to it's place, the overhead pass away and the performance is what I expect. So the problem should lie somewhere in the `static_cast`s.

Do I something wrong in my CRTP casts, or this is a weakness of MSVC again?

**EDIT**

I include a working code which can be easily tested with a simple timer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

template <typename T, size_t N, typename Derived>
struct Base
{
    __forceinline Derived& operator+=(const Derived &b)
    {
        return (static_cast<Derived&>(*this) = static_cast<Derived&>(*this) + b);
    }
};

// same as Base, but with manually inlined operator+
template <typename T, size_t N, typename Derived>
struct Base2
{
    __forceinline Derived& operator+=(const Derived &b)
    {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->data[0] += b.data[0];
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->data[1] += b.data[1];
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->data[2] += b.data[2];
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->data[3] += b.data[3];

        return static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
    }
};

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct A: Base<T,N, A<T,N>>
{
    T data[N];
};

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct B: Base2<T,N, B<T,N>>
{
    T data[N];
};

template <typename T, size_t N>
__forceinline A<T, N> operator+(const A<T, N> &a, const A<T, N> &b)
{
    A<T, N> result;

    result.data[0] = a.data[0] + b.data[0];
    result.data[1] = a.data[1] + b.data[1];
    result.data[2] = a.data[2] + b.data[2];
    result.data[3] = a.data[3] + b.data[3];

    return result;
}

template <class Func>
void runtime_print(Func &&func, size_t n, std::string label)
{
    auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        func(i);
    }
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t1 - t0).count();

    std::cout << label << " : " << t << '\n';
}


int main()
{
    size_t n = 10000000;

    A <float,4> a0;
    A <float,4> a1;

    B <float,4> b0;
    B <float,4> b1;

    // this is slow
    runtime_print([&](size_t i)
    {
        a0 += a1;
    }, n, "a0");

    // this is fast
    runtime_print([&](size_t i)
    {
        b0 += b1;
    }, n, "b0");

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: I get the opposite results from yours. Second loop for me is 4x slower. Are you building Release?

Comment: I see the edit. Then the question is - how do you measure?

Comment: With QueryPerformanceCounter. It is monotonic and high resolution (at least on modern Windows platforms). Did you use Visual Studio 2015 Update 1?

Comment: [OT]: Note that parameters `T` and `N` seem unneeded for `Base`.

Comment: About the same results I get with VS 2015 Update 1 (measured using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock, which uses QueryPerformanceCounter IIRC): first loop: 92,894us; second loop: 368,534us (100 million iterations)

Comment: @Jarod42 They are not unneeded in the original version of the class. This is a stripped down version to clearly represent the problematic parts.

Comment: Ok, I used steady_clock, which uses same QueryPerformanceCounter under the hood so it doesn't matter. Let me try with update 1 (time to install it anyway :))

Comment: You should initialize `a0`, `a1`, `b0`, `b1`.

Comment: @Jarod42 interestingly, that didn't change much for me. However, if I switch the storage to `std::array<T,N>`, both loops perform nearly the same at ~100-110 ms.

Comment: I have updated the test code. Maybe the lambda function of runtime_print complicates the things here. Although that raises a question that why lambda functions aren't inlined properly.

Comment: @plasmacel your two implementations are not equivalent. If you remove the unecessary copies everywhere, suddenly they perform the same for me: https://gist.github.com/melak47/5b625f4c9ddb021aff93

Comment: (and std::array is still faster for some reason :))

Comment: @melak47 Well, yes, but the aim was that pattern is to avoid defining every compound assignment (+=,-=,*=, etc) operators. I expected that MSVC will optimize away the unnecessary copy instructions, just like GCC and Clang does. Furthermore it's pretty weird that it optimizes away if you invoke the operator outside a lambda, and it doesn't if you invoke the operator inside a lambda.

Comment: @melak47 Nevertheless your solution is better and more secure, maybe that's the way how should it be done, thanks.

Comment: You avoided implementing `operator+=` for A...by implementing it on top of `operator+`, which you still had to implement? Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Well, yes. That way If I change the logic of operator+, operator+= implicitly changes. This seems purely lazy, but If you have all the arithmetic/bitwise operators this can halve the work when you change something. This is especially useful when you deal with matrices, where operator* overloads aren't that trivial.

Comment: Yes, but usually that goes the other way - you implement `+` in terms of `+=`, not the other way around.